# Laravel displays blank page after renaming a page

Tags: php, laravel

I renamed my index.blade.php file in my 'cluster' folder into overview.blade.php and all of a sudden cluster/overview displays a blank page. I renamed all my other methods pointing towards the page so I am not sure what is going wrong here. I think it has to do with renaming the index

EDIT: added the relevant code

VIEW

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@include('modal')
@section('content')
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <button class="button -dark center">
                    <a href="/home" class="previous round" style="color: white">&#8249;  Home</a>
                </button>
                <a href="/cluster/create">
                    <button type="submit"  class="button -green center float-right">Voeg cluster toe</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"><strong>Cluster naam</strong></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($departments as $department)
                <tr>
                    <form action="{{route('deletecluster', $department->id)}}" method="post" id="submit-button">
                        <td>{{$department->name}}</td>
                        @csrf
                        <td><a href="{{url('cluster/edit/' . $department->id)}}"><button  type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registration">Bewerken</button></a></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Verwijderen</button></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table >
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit-button').on('submit', function(e){
                $('#registration').modal('show');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
@endsection
```

ROUTING

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});

Route::resource('event', 'EventController');
Route::resource('cluster', 'ClusterController');

Route::get('calendar', 'EventController@calendar');
Route::get('export', 'EventController@export');

Route::get('user/create', 'UserController@create');
Route::get('user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@edit');
Route::get('cluster/edit/{id}', 'ClusterController@edit');
Route::get('user/settings', 'UserController@settings')->name('settings');
Route::post('user/store', 'UserController@store');
Route::post('user/employeeStore', 'UserController@employeeStore');
Route::post('user/store_settings', 'UserController@settingsStore');

Route::post('user/addShift', 'UserController@addShift');
Route::post('user/togglemail', 'UserController@toggleMail');
Route::get('user/overview', 'UserController@overview');
Route::get('cluster/overview', 'ClusterController@overview')->name('overview');

Route::post('user/delete{id}', 'UserController@deleteUser')->name('deleteuser');
Route::post('cluster/delete{id}','ClusterController@deleteCluster')->name('deletecluster');
Route::post('event/store', 'EventController@store');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

//Route::get('laravel-send-email', 'EmailController@sendMail');

Route::get('user/changepassword', 'UserController@changePassword');
Route::post('user/updatepassword', 'UserController@updatePassword')->name('updatepassword');
```

CONTROLLER

```
class ClusterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function overview()
    {
        $departments = Department::all();
        return view ('cluster.overview')->with('departments', $departments);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $shift_types = shift_type::all();
        return view('cluster.create')->with('shift_types', $shift_types);
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $department = new Department();
        $department->name = $request->input('clustername');
        $department->save();

        $typeArray = explode(',', $request->input('types'));
        foreach($typeArray as $type) {
            $shift_type = new ShiftType();
            $shift_type ->shift_name = $type;
            $shift_type->save();
            $department_shift_type = new DepartmentShiftType();
            $department_shift_type->department_id = $department->id;
            $department_shift_type->shift_type_id =  $shift_type->id;
            $department_shift_type->save();

        }
        return $department->id;
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $departmentshift = DepartmentShiftType::findOrFail($id);
        $departmentshifts = DepartmentShiftType::all();
        $shifts = ShiftType::all();
        $shift = ShiftType::findOrFail($id);
        $shift_id = $departmentshift->shift_type_id;
        $department = Department::findOrFail($id);
        return view('cluster.edit')->with('department', $department)->with('departmentshift', $departmentshift)->with('shift_id', $shift_id)->with('departmentshifts', $departmentshifts)->with('shifts', $shifts)->with('shift', $shift    );
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function deleteCluster($id)
    {
        $department = Department::findOrFail($id);
        $department->delete();

        return redirect('cluster.overview');
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the code in your route file, controller, view

Comment: added the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line:

`Route::get('cluster/overview', 'ClusterController@overview')->name('overview');`

above this one:

`Route::resource('cluster', 'ClusterController');`

Laravel thinks you are trying to call this route:
`/cluster/{cluster}`

```
public function show($id)
{
    //
}
```

You can confirm this by adding some return value in the `show` method

```
public function show($id)
{
   dd('foobar');
}
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick! Why does it think that I am trying to call that route?

Comment: `Route::resource` creates a group of "resourceful" routes: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers. check with `php artisan route:list`